# Adding pagination to my index view in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

Mine is an asp.net mvc application. I have an index view with rows more than 25. This makes my page render slow. I need to implement pagination in this. I want to limit the no of rows to 6 or so. Please can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
namespace Comtesys.WebUI.Models
{
    public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
        }
    }
}
```

HtmlHelper:

```
namespace Comtesys.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        } 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult List(int page = 1)
 {
    public int PageSize = 6;
            var viewModel = new YourModel
            {
                ListItems = _repository.SomeCollection,
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = _repository.SomeCollection.Count()
                }
            };

            return View(viewModel);
}
```

Using:

```
<div class="pager">
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Comment: how should the controller be?

Answer (score 0):

For paginating results I use [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) it's easy to use, small and clean. (and of course there's good docs and samples).